# "docker" command not found - Google cloud platform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

```
C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth ---
You are now logged in as [chriskwon7007@gmail.com].
Your current project is [nodejs-301100].  You can change this setting by running:
$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth configure-docker
WARNING: `docker` not in system PATH.
`docker` and `docker-credential-gcloud` need to be in the same PATH in order to work correctly 
together.
gcloud's Docker credential helper can be configured but it will not work until this is corrected.
WARNING: Your config file at [C:\Users\chris\.docker\config.json] contains these credential helper entries:

{
"credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
   }
}
Adding credentials for all GCR repositories.
WARNING: A long list of credential helpers may cause delays running 'docker build'. We recommend passing the registry name to configure only the registry you are using.
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.

C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>docker pull asia.gcr.io/nodejs-301100/appengine/default.20210108t204554:latest
'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I excuted the "docker pull" command from the Gcp Container registry.
But Shell occurs "command not found" error.

[What I was guided by Google cloud support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92XHI.png)

How can I run this command without errors?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/

Comment: If you really have installed Docker, check that it's in your system PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your latop/system does not have docker setup. Please setup docker on windows first. Or alternatively use google cloud shell to run the commands.

Comment: I was so stupid that I didn't think I had to install the docker. Thanks!